# "Script" command for two terminals

Tags: typescript

I want to run script command such that it logs both the commands I type for the server and the client in one script file. How can I possibly do this ?

Comment: Are your client and server running in different (terminal) sessions? Or are they managed from the same command line?

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of the client and server within the same terminal you can use the `script` command to capture input/output from that session. Simply type it (on a line by itself) before you start your client/server program and it will write all input/output to a file called `typescript`. Use *Ctrl/D* to exit when you're done.

Comment: It sounds to me like the OP is talking about how to use the `script` command, but it's unclear

Comment: @Michael, ah. Perhaps I've misunderstood the OP and they've got two separate terminal sessions. I'd assumed one session and that they didn't know about `script`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to record a whole `screen` or `tmux`, split the terminal into multiple panes and ssh on the server in one of them:

```
$ screen -t session.tm session.log
$ tmux
[C-b "]
$ ssh server.example.org
```